# return exit code of process in shell

Tags: node.js, bash, sh

I have this function in .bash_profile

```
function suman {
       LOCAL_SUMAN=$(node $HOME/.suman/find-local-suman-executable.js);

       if [ -z "$LOCAL_SUMAN" ]; then
           echo "No local Suman executable could be found, given the current directory => $PWD"
           return 1;
       else
           return node "$LOCAL_SUMAN" "$@";  # this is wrong I think
       fi

  }
```

I just want to return the exit code of the node process, but I think the line above is incorrect, what is correct way to return the correct exit code from the suman function?

I would have guessed the exit code would be "returned" by the node process on the same line.

Perhaps I should just remove the return keyword?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `return` in that line; just call `node "$LOCAL_SUMAN" "$@"`; since it is the last command executed by your function, your function will exit with the same return status as the call to `node`.

```
suman () {
   LOCAL_SUMAN=$(node $HOME/.suman/find-local-suman-executable.js)

   if [ -z "$LOCAL_SUMAN" ]; then
       echo "No local Suman executable could be found, given the current directory => $PWD"
       return 1
   else
       node "$LOCAL_SUMAN" "$@"
   fi
}
```

Comment: thanks, I wonder why the return statement is incorrect though? I had an error when I used that, trying to reproduce the error, but haven't yet

Comment: You can assign the returncode like `suman_retcode=$?` in the line directly following the node statement and the use `$suman_retcode` where you need it. Note that if you do anything else between the node and the returncode assignment you'll get the return code of that anything and not what you intended.

Comment: `return` *only* takes a single integer to use as the return status, not an arbitrary command.